# AttributeError: '_unknown' object has no attribute 'id' in odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo

here's my problem, whenever i update my app in odoo and click on my wizard to create a report
this error pops up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 916, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1342, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1334, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 464, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 451, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 6498, in onchange
    result['value'] = snapshot1.diff(snapshot0, force=first_call)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 6322, in diff
    result[name] = field.convert_to_onchange(self[name], record, {})
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 2840, in convert_to_onchange
    if not value.id:
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
AttributeError: '_unknown' object has no attribute 'id'
```

it really doesnt tell me anything, but it only appears when i update the app not before it

this is the line of code im trying to update

```
def compute_reporte(self):
    for rec in self:
        # pivo = rec.env[]
        obj = rec.env['mrp.production.cab'].search([("lot_producing_id", "=", rec.lot_producing_id.id)])
        ordenado = obj.sorted(key=lambda r: r.date_planned_start)

        nom_lot = obj.lot_producing_id.name
        lista_mat = obj.bom_id.bom_line_ids.product_id.id
        nom_brut = rec.env['stock.production.lot'].search([("product_id", "=", lista_mat)])
        for x in nom_brut:
            if x.name == nom_lot:
                pivo_id = x.id

        lot = rec.env['stock.move.line'].search([("lot_id", "=", pivo_id)])
        print("xdxdxdxdxd")
        tot_cost = 0
        prov = ""
        for x in lot.picking_id:
            tot_cost += x.update_costs
            prov = x.partner_id.name
            print(x.partner_id.name)
        rec.update({"costototal_reporte": tot_cost})
        rec.update({"cod_proveedor": prov})
        print(rec.costototal_reporte)

        # for x in lot:
        #     pic = rec.env['stock.picking'].search([("type", "=", x.id)])
        #     print("yayayayayay")

        cos = rec.env['stock.picking'].search([("id", "=", rec.lot_producing_id.id)])
        ordenado3 = cos.sorted(key=lambda r: r.date_done)

        pivo = rec.env['mrp.routing.workcenter.cab'].search([('id', '=', self.production_cab_id.id)])
        rec.horas_reporte = pivo.duration

        for x in pivo:
            if x.workcenter_cab_ids:
                rec.cod_linea_work = x.workcenter_cab_ids.cod_linea_work.id

        prov = self.env['mrp.production.cab'].search(
            [('company_id', '=', self.company_id.id), ("lot_producing_id", "=", rec.lot_producing_id.id)])
        self.cod_proveedor = prov.cod_proveedor.id
        print("nombre de proveedor")
        print(self.cod_proveedor)
        print(prov.cod_proveedor)
        print(prov.cod_proveedor.id)

        if len(ordenado) == 1:
            print("cantidad de horas")
            print(ordenado[0].horas_reporte)
            for x in self:
                pivot = x.env['mrp.routing.workcenter.cab'].search(
                    [('company_id', '=', self.company_id.id), ('production_cab_id', '=', x.id)])
                if pivot.duration:
                    dato = pivot.duration
                    calculo = dato / 60
                    print(pivot.hora_convertido)
                    self.update({"horas_reporte": pivot.hora_convertido})
                    print(self.horas_reporte)
            rec.update({"bruto_reporte": ordenado[0].product_qty})
            rec.update({"bruto_reporte2": ordenado[0].product_qty})
            rec.update({"final_reporte": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing})
            rec.update({"final_reporte2": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing})
            rec.update({"final_porce": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].product_final_porce})
            rec.update({"final_porce2": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].product_final_porce})
            rec.update({"bb_reporte": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].bibag_count})
            rec.update({"bb_reporte2": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].bibag_count})
            rec.update({"pureza_reporte": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio})
            rec.update({"pureza_reporte2": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio})
            rec.update({"humedad_reporte": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].humedad})
            rec.update({"humedad_reporte2": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].humedad})
            rec.update({"big_bag_promedio_final": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio_final})
            rec.update({"merma": ordenado[0].product_qty - ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing})
            rec.update({"merma_porce": (ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].merma / (ordenado[0].product_qty)) * 100})
            rec.update({"merma_porce2": (ordenado[0].merma / (ordenado[0].product_qty)) * 100})
            rec.update({"horas_reporte": calculo})

            # if len(ordenado3) == 1:
            #     rec.update({"costototal_reporte": ordenado3[0].update_costs})
            #     rec.update({"costo_kg_reporte": ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[0].product_qty})
            #     rec.update(
            #         {"costo_final_reporte": ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing})

            if ordenado[0].merma == ordenado[0].product_qty:
                ordenado[0].merma = 0


        elif len(ordenado) > 1:
            mer_por = 0
            cont = 0
            for ll in ordenado:
                if ll.tipo_producto == '1' or ll.tipo_producto == '4':
                    cont = cont + 1
                    for x in self:
                        pivot = x.env['mrp.routing.workcenter.cab'].search(
                            [('company_id', '=', self.company_id.id), ('production_cab_id', '=', x.id)])
                        if pivot.duration:
                            dato = pivot.duration
                            calculo = dato / 60
                            print(pivot.hora_convertido)
                            self.update({"horas_reporte": pivot.hora_convertido})
                            print(self.horas_reporte)
                elif ll.tipo_producto == '2' or ll.tipo_producto == '3':
                    print("no es nuevo producto o reproceso")
            valor_menor2 = ordenado[0].product_qty
            valor_menor = ordenado[0].product_qty / cont
            valor_mayor2 = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing
            valor_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing / cont
            porce_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].product_final_porce / cont
            bigbag_mayor2 = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].bibag_count
            bigbag_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].bibag_count / cont
            pureza_mayor2 = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio
            pureza_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio / cont
            humedad_mayor2 = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].humedad
            humedad_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].humedad / cont
            nota_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio_final / cont

            if len(ordenado3) > 1:
                costo_mayor = ordenado3[0].update_costs / cont
                costo_mayor2 = ordenado3[0].update_costs
                costo_kg = ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[0].product_qty / cont
                costo_kg2 = ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[0].product_qty / cont
                costo_final = ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing / cont
                costo_final2 = ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing
                ll.update({"costototal_reporte": costo_mayor})
                ll.update({"costo_kg_reporte": costo_kg})
                ll.update({"costo_final_reporte": costo_final})
                ll.update({"costototal_reporte2": costo_mayor2})
                ll.update({"costo_kg_reporte2": costo_kg2})
                ll.update({"costo_final_reporte2": costo_final2})

            for ll in ordenado:
                ll.update({"bruto_reporte": valor_menor})
                ll.update({"final_reporte": valor_mayor})
                ll.update({"final_porce": porce_mayor})
                ll.update({"bb_reporte": bigbag_mayor})
                ll.update({"pureza_reporte": pureza_mayor})
                ll.update({"humedad_reporte": humedad_mayor})
                ll.update({"big_bag_promedio_final": nota_mayor})

                ll.update({"bruto_reporte2": valor_menor2})
                ll.update({"final_reporte2": valor_mayor2})
                # ll.update({"final_porce2": porce_mayor2})
                ll.update({"bb_reporte2": bigbag_mayor2})
                ll.update({"pureza_reporte2": pureza_mayor2})
                ll.update({"humedad_reporte2": humedad_mayor2})
                ll.update({"big_bag_promedio_final": nota_mayor})

                if ll.tipo_producto == '1' or ll.tipo_producto == '4':
                    mer_por = mer_por + ll.merma
                    cont = cont + 1
                elif ll.tipo_producto == '2' or ll.tipo_producto == '3':
                    print("no es nuevo producto o reproceso")

            rec.update({"merma_porce": ((mer_por / ordenado[0].product_qty) * 100) / cont})
            rec.update({"merma_porce2": ((mer_por / ordenado[0].product_qty) * 100)})
            rec.update({"merma2": mer_por})
```

```
def compute_reporte(self):
    for rec in self:
        # pivo = rec.env[]
        obj = rec.env['mrp.production.cab'].search([("lot_producing_id", "=", rec.lot_producing_id.id)])
        ordenado = obj.sorted(key=lambda r: r.date_planned_start)

        nom_lot = obj.lot_producing_id.name
        lista_mat = obj.bom_id.bom_line_ids.product_id.id
        nom_brut = rec.env['stock.production.lot'].search([("product_id", "=", lista_mat)])
        for x in nom_brut:
            if x.name == nom_lot:
                pivo_id = x.id

        lot = rec.env['stock.move.line'].search([("lot_id", "=", pivo_id)])
        print("xdxdxdxdxd")
        tot_cost = 0
        prov = ""
        for x in lot.picking_id:
            tot_cost += x.update_costs
            prov = x.partner_id.name
            print(x.partner_id.name)
        rec.update({"costototal_reporte": tot_cost})
        rec.update({"cod_proveedor": prov})
        print(rec.costototal_reporte)

        # for x in lot:
        #     pic = rec.env['stock.picking'].search([("type", "=", x.id)])
        #     print("yayayayayay")

        cos = rec.env['stock.picking'].search([("id", "=", rec.lot_producing_id.id)])
        ordenado3 = cos.sorted(key=lambda r: r.date_done)

        pivo = rec.env['mrp.routing.workcenter.cab'].search([('id', '=', self.production_cab_id.id)])
        rec.horas_reporte = pivo.duration

        for x in pivo:
            if x.workcenter_cab_ids:
                rec.cod_linea_work = x.workcenter_cab_ids.cod_linea_work.id

        prov = self.env['mrp.production.cab'].search(
            [('company_id', '=', self.company_id.id), ("lot_producing_id", "=", rec.lot_producing_id.id)])
        self.cod_proveedor = prov.cod_proveedor.id
        print("nombre de proveedor")
        print(self.cod_proveedor)
        print(prov.cod_proveedor)
        print(prov.cod_proveedor.id)

        if len(ordenado) == 1:
            print("cantidad de horas")
            print(ordenado[0].horas_reporte)
            for x in self:
                pivot = x.env['mrp.routing.workcenter.cab'].search(
                    [('company_id', '=', self.company_id.id), ('production_cab_id', '=', x.id)])
                if pivot.duration:
                    dato = pivot.duration
                    calculo = dato / 60
                    print(pivot.hora_convertido)
                    self.update({"horas_reporte": pivot.hora_convertido})
                    print(self.horas_reporte)
            rec.update({"bruto_reporte": ordenado[0].product_qty})
            rec.update({"bruto_reporte2": ordenado[0].product_qty})
            rec.update({"final_reporte": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing})
            rec.update({"final_reporte2": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing})
            rec.update({"final_porce": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].product_final_porce})
            rec.update({"final_porce2": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].product_final_porce})
            rec.update({"bb_reporte": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].bibag_count})
            rec.update({"bb_reporte2": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].bibag_count})
            rec.update({"pureza_reporte": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio})
            rec.update({"pureza_reporte2": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio})
            rec.update({"humedad_reporte": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].humedad})
            rec.update({"humedad_reporte2": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].humedad})
            rec.update({"big_bag_promedio_final": ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio_final})
            rec.update({"merma": ordenado[0].product_qty - ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing})
            rec.update({"merma_porce": (ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].merma / (ordenado[0].product_qty)) * 100})
            rec.update({"merma_porce2": (ordenado[0].merma / (ordenado[0].product_qty)) * 100})
            rec.update({"horas_reporte": calculo})

            # if len(ordenado3) == 1:
            #     rec.update({"costototal_reporte": ordenado3[0].update_costs})
            #     rec.update({"costo_kg_reporte": ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[0].product_qty})
            #     rec.update(
            #         {"costo_final_reporte": ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing})

            if ordenado[0].merma == ordenado[0].product_qty:
                ordenado[0].merma = 0


        elif len(ordenado) > 1:
            mer_por = 0
            cont = 0
            for ll in ordenado:
                if ll.tipo_producto == '1' or ll.tipo_producto == '4':
                    cont = cont + 1
                    for x in self:
                        pivot = x.env['mrp.routing.workcenter.cab'].search(
                            [('company_id', '=', self.company_id.id), ('production_cab_id', '=', x.id)])
                        if pivot.duration:
                            dato = pivot.duration
                            calculo = dato / 60
                            print(pivot.hora_convertido)
                            self.update({"horas_reporte": pivot.hora_convertido})
                            print(self.horas_reporte)
                elif ll.tipo_producto == '2' or ll.tipo_producto == '3':
                    print("no es nuevo producto o reproceso")
            valor_menor2 = ordenado[0].product_qty
            valor_menor = ordenado[0].product_qty / cont
            valor_mayor2 = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing
            valor_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing / cont
            porce_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].product_final_porce / cont
            bigbag_mayor2 = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].bibag_count
            bigbag_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].bibag_count / cont
            pureza_mayor2 = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio
            pureza_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio / cont
            humedad_mayor2 = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].humedad
            humedad_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].humedad / cont
            nota_mayor = ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].big_bag_promedio_final / cont

            if len(ordenado3) > 1:
                costo_mayor = ordenado3[0].update_costs / cont
                costo_mayor2 = ordenado3[0].update_costs
                costo_kg = ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[0].product_qty / cont
                costo_kg2 = ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[0].product_qty / cont
                costo_final = ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing / cont
                costo_final2 = ordenado3[0].update_costs / ordenado[len(ordenado) - 1].qty_producing
                ll.update({"costototal_reporte": costo_mayor})
                ll.update({"costo_kg_reporte": costo_kg})
                ll.update({"costo_final_reporte": costo_final})
                ll.update({"costototal_reporte2": costo_mayor2})
                ll.update({"costo_kg_reporte2": costo_kg2})
                ll.update({"costo_final_reporte2": costo_final2})

            for ll in ordenado:
                ll.update({"bruto_reporte": valor_menor})
                ll.update({"final_reporte": valor_mayor})
                ll.update({"final_porce": porce_mayor})
                ll.update({"bb_reporte": bigbag_mayor})
                ll.update({"pureza_reporte": pureza_mayor})
                ll.update({"humedad_reporte": humedad_mayor})
                ll.update({"big_bag_promedio_final": nota_mayor})

                ll.update({"bruto_reporte2": valor_menor2})
                ll.update({"final_reporte2": valor_mayor2})
                # ll.update({"final_porce2": porce_mayor2})
                ll.update({"bb_reporte2": bigbag_mayor2})
                ll.update({"pureza_reporte2": pureza_mayor2})
                ll.update({"humedad_reporte2": humedad_mayor2})
                ll.update({"big_bag_promedio_final": nota_mayor})

                if ll.tipo_producto == '1' or ll.tipo_producto == '4':
                    mer_por = mer_por + ll.merma
                    cont = cont + 1
                elif ll.tipo_producto == '2' or ll.tipo_producto == '3':
                    print("no es nuevo producto o reproceso")

            rec.update({"merma_porce": ((mer_por / ordenado[0].product_qty) * 100) / cont})
            rec.update({"merma_porce2": ((mer_por / ordenado[0].product_qty) * 100)})
            rec.update({"merma2": mer_por})
```

sorry for the long post and thank you in advance

updated my app in odoo 15 and then that error appeared whenever i wanted to display my wizard

Comment: Check Many2one fields, you used a model which does not exist